# RAM as a attack target

Tags: attacks, access-control, forensics, cold-boot-attack, swap

What is the simplest or most common method to read a value, for example a text, from the RAM of a personal computer?
What access requirements are necessary for this? Is a search in a hex dump always required or are there shorter ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you tagged this question as "cold boot attack" and "forensics", I presume you're asking about a physical memory dump.

These dumps are usually acquired by something like [pcileech](https://github.com/ufrisk/pcileech), using a special hardware device as an interface to the target system's memory. You may also acquire a memory dump from a crash dump or some other forensic tool. Generally you're copying the entire contents of physical memory into a dump file for later analysis.

Once you've got a memory dump, it's possible to just search through it using a hex editor, but generally people use tools like [volatility](https://github.com/volatilityfoundation/volatility) to analyse them. This provides much more information about the state of the system, since it can parse various operating system structures.